# How to access multiple USB Type B storage devices at once?

Tags: usb

I have multiple devices with USB Type B ports for exporting data.
I am told that it is a 1:1 device. I would like to plug in 1 computer to read the data from 1 device. I am looking for a way that I could 'network' them so I can read them all from one computer. Has anyone done this, have any ideas on how I might do this?

Comment: Why don't you just network them using CAT5 cable?  I suppose you could use USB Switches to acomplish this, you don't indicate, how many machines you have exactly.

Comment: What device are we talking about? A poorly designed device driver could indeed be limited to a single device even though a USB Host (your PC) could acommodate many.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt provide much detail in your question, so its hard to understand exactly what you are talking about.

But if the devices are standard USB devices, all you need is a USB hub like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XMD7KPU).  You can buy one with more ports, or daisy chain them.  Plug the hub into your computer and your devices into the hub.  If your devices draw a lot of power, you might need a powered hub like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00483WRZ6).

If necessary, purchase USB A to B [cables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003PXPQA8).

Answer (score 0):

> I am told that it is a 1:1 device.

Who told it to you?

He probably meant that with one USB cable you can connect only one device to only one computer.

But nothing prevent you to use different USB ports to connect to multiple devices, or to use USB hub similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the data from your device after it has been exported? A simple network share would do.

1. Select a machine that will hold the files the other machines will access.
2. Create a shared folder with public access on the local network.
3. Export the data to the shared folder
4. Open the share folder on the other computers

The files are now available to anyone on your local network.

Note: Allowing public access is a bit of a security issue. Anyone that connects to your local network will be able to see the files and edit/delete them.